# Detecting keystrokes outside of the form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent

I'm also finished in making my own auto-clicker application and I've noticed that the only way to start the program is to press the selected hot-key while the form is selected. For obvious reasons, I would like for the application to begin even if the form is not selected.

Long story short, how am I able to detect keystrokes even while the form is "unfocused"/not selected?

Answer (score -1):

you can use hooks:

http://revolt.alexjf.net/blog.php?action=read&item=15

although this is a key-logger tutorial, ill say you can learn much from this